# Copy the Linux kernel config file to another distribution

Tags: linux, kernel, boot, gentoo

I am installing new Linux distro (gentoo) and I want to copy the linux kernel config I have here in the linux mint live USB to the Gentoo system. The way Mint has the kernel config file is `/boot/config-3.19.0-32-generic` but in Gentoo it has to be `/proc/config.gz` (specific file path in this situation is `/mnt/gentoo/proc/config.gz`). Could I take the `config-3.19.0.32-generic` and turn it into `config.gz` and just copy? Is there other way to do this?

Comment: `/proc` is runtime-generated, so `/proc/config.gz` is always the config used to build the currently running kernel. Both `/boot/config...` and `/proc/config.gz` are used to have a config file to use when you want to compile the Linux kernel (which you should do for Gentoo).

Comment: [Why do you want to do this?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1):

.gz is a **gzip** format, read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip

You can compress the file and then move it.

```
gzip /boot/config-3.19.0-32-generic
mv /boot/config-3.19.0-32-generic.gz /mnt/gentoo/proc/config.gz
```

Comment: That should be probably `... /mnt/gentoo/proc/config.gz` as copying to live `/proc` filesystem might not work as intended.

Comment: @zagrimsan yes, updated

Answer (score 0):

### Do the Following

1. On a Windows Machine, use [LiLiCreator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/) to create a USB, containing the Gentoo LiveCD.
2. Boot your Mint Version.
3. Mount the Gentoo Live USB in Mint. I'll assume **sdb**.
4. Issue roxto's command, `gzip /boot/config-version && mv /boot/config-version.gz /dev/sdb`
5. Boot the Gentoo Live USB.
6. Follow the [Gentoo Handbook](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64) Step by Step to [Configuring the Linux kernel](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Installation/Kernel)
7. During the [Preparing the Disks](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Installation/Disks) step, you need to issue: `cp /config-version.gz /mnt/gentoo/boot`
8. You must now match Kernel Versions.  To do that, read [the post I helped answer on Masked Kernel Versions](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-7410070.html).
9. Note that you **WILL HAVE ISSUES**, as our Package Maintainers don't have a 3.19.x Kernel Version.  See the [Gentoo Sources Package](https://packages.gentoo.org/packages/sys-kernel/gentoo-sources).  Knowing this you need install a Matching version in Mint before you do this procedure, using the Update Manager in Mint.  See [Question 3 here](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/20#TOC-Consider-installing-kernel-updates).
10. Rename your File in step 4 to `.config` and move it to `/usr/src/linux` and then follow the manual configuration option in the handbook.